# Are independent variable infinitesimals positive?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, infinitesimals

A calculation I'm doing involves the inequality $$\frac{dt}{dx}\leq \frac{-kt}{x}$$ and I want to shift the dx and t to the other sides, so I can integrate.
Now t is known to be positive (it's $xf(x)$, where f is a function and both x and f are positive), so I assume I can shift it.

But I'm not sure about $dx$. I could consider it the independent variable on the graph of f, and say it's defined to be positive, while I can't say the same for dt, since as a function it may increase or decrease.

Is this assumption correct?

Comment: If you know $k,t,x \gt 0$ then you know $\frac{dt}{dx} \lt 0$

Comment: If t's increasing at a point, wouldn't it be positive?

Comment: If $\frac{-kt}{x}$ is negative then $\frac{dt}{dx}$ would be more negative

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's right. But is the thing about dx being positive okay?

Comment: It kinda depends what you're planning on doing/why you need to know. I think we'd need more context. For example, if $dt/dx=-7$, then *decreasing* $x$ by a tiny bit $h>0$ would increase $dt$ by about $7h$. If you call that tiny $-h$ change to $x$ "$dx$", then $dx$ would be negative. But under the assumption that $t$ is differentiable, knowing what happens for positive changes in $x$ is enough to understand what's approximately going on, so some arguments could safely assume something like "$dx$ is positive".

Comment: @MarkS.: Hmm. I was talking about the use of dx in, say, statements like "$\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $x^2$ at x=1 is 2". I get what you mean; that dy could be measured 'downwards-positive', and dx 'leftwards-negative'. I wanted to know if by *convention* we take dx as the positive value, and specify otherwise if necessary, so that in this case, I could shift the dx without worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Question

If I understand correctly, the main question is essentially:

> If $f(y)\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\le g(x)$, can we "multiply both sides by $\mathrm dx$" and then integrate, as we might with an equation?

## Main Answer

It's a [property of definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Inequalities) that if $f(x)\le g(x)$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx\le \int_a^bg(x)\,\mathrm dx$. Therefore, if we have $f(y)\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\le g(x)$ for relevant values of $x$, we may write $\int_a^Xf(y)\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\,\mathrm dx\le \int_a^Xg(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and use [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals) to rewrite the integral on the left as ${\displaystyle \int_{{\displaystyle y\mid_{x=a}}}^{{\displaystyle y\mid_{x=X}}}}f(y)\,\mathrm dy$. If $F$ and $G$ are antiderivatives for $f$ and $g$, respectively, then [FTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) says that the inequality becomes $F\left({\displaystyle y\mid_{x=X}}\right)-F\left({\displaystyle y\mid_{x=a}}\right)\le G\left(X\right)-G(a)$. Setting $C$ to be the contstant $F\left({\displaystyle y\mid_{x=a}}\right)-G(a)$, we could write this as $F\left({\displaystyle y\mid_{x=X}}\right)\le G\left(X\right)+C$. In more common notation, we have $F(y)\le G(x)+C$.

For comparison, if we were to "multiply both sides by $\mathrm dx$" and integrate as we would typically do for a [separable differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Ordinary_differential_equations_(ODE)), we'd have $\int f(y)\,\mathrm dy\le\int g(x)\,\mathrm dx$ and immediately arrive at $F(y)\le G(x)+C$.

Since we arrive at the same inequality as in the argument that did not rely on uncertain properties about multiplying through by $\mathrm dx$, this method **is valid**. Whether you want to think about it as "treating $\mathrm dx$ as positive" is probably a matter of personal taste.

---

## Edit/Note

However, we can also do the same careful steps with $\int_X^b$ instead, to find that $F\left({\displaystyle y\mid_{x=b}}\right)-F\left({\displaystyle y\mid_{x=X}}\right)\le G\left(b\right)-G(X)$, and hence there is a constant $C_2=F\left({\displaystyle y\mid_{x=b}}\right)-G\left(b\right)$ for which $G(x)+C_2\le F(y)$.

This is the result we would have obtained by multiplying through by $\mathrm dx$ *and flipping the inequality sign* and integrating. In this sense, $\mathrm dx$ is perhaps best considered as "either positive and negative", since we have $G(x)+C_2\le F(y)\le G(x)+C_1$.

Comment: I see, thanks for the edit to the already comprehensive answer. So I guess we'll throw convention out of the window for the sake of rigor, and think of dx in a graphical way, depending on the situation?

Comment: @HarryHolmes When we take a definite integral of both sides of the inequality, we essentially need to take an undirected integral like $\int_{[a,x]}$ or $\int_{[x,b]}$, so that the bounds of $\int_a^x$ are written in increasing order. But the fundamental theorem of calculus (related to the indefinite integrals we'd like to write) works whether or not the bounds are in increasing order; and backwards bounds are kind of like $dx$ being negative. This sort of thing is discussed a bit in Terry Tao's [differential forms and integration](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf) preprint.